# D3 Pick Multivalue Database Access ODBC or other?

Tags: odbc, pick

Hello I am very new to D3 Pick. Could you recommend some info on how to get access to a data file with possibly ODBC or SQL query? My IT department says ODBC is not possible but I think there must be a way. Maybe creating a new pointer file to be set up for ODBC? I'm still learning about the structure of D3 and file system. I am more familiar using MS SQL Server so any clarification is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocket Software does provide an ODBC server for D3. Compatibility depends on the version of D3 you are running. The documentation for D3 can be found here: https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/index.jsp

If you have an active support contract with Rocket you can also reach out to their support for assistance in getting ODBC server running, otherwise I would also recommend signing up for their forum and posting there as their support also monitors it as well.

You may also want to look MVS Toolkit which can be used to generate SOAP and REST apis as another method of accessing your D3 data remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Pick d3 has a proprietary odbc that gives access to its own api to access data from a windows environment.

[This is the url with the index of the access api](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/odbc/203/userguide/index.htm)

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). Please [edit] the post to translate it. Additionally, Stack Overflow strives to be a professional database with programming knowledge, not your friendly neighbourhood help desk. As such, salutations and the like have not place here. Take the [tour] and read up on [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).